# Append an element inside another one already appended

Tags: jquery, html

I know how to append an element in another element, but how can I do this one more time? In my example when I press the `+ Title` button, it appends an element and when when I press `Add Subtitle`, I have another one.

However when I press the `Comment` button, I want to append my `<p>Comment</p>` just under the subtitle section. How can I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
    $('ul').append('<li> Title <input id="title" type="button" value="Add Subtitle" /></li>');
  });

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).append('</br>Subtitle <input id="sub" type="button" value="Comment" />');
  });

  $('li').on('click', '#sub', function () {
    $(this).append('<p>Comments</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="font-family:Arial">
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+ Title" />
    <ul>
        <li>Title <input id="title" type="button" value="Add Subtitle"/></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
          $('ul').append('<li> Title <input id="title" type="button" value="Add Subtitle" /></li>');
      });

      $('ul').on('click', '#title', function () {
           $(this).closest('li').append('<p>Subtitle <input id="sub" type="button" value="Comment" /></p>');
      });

      $(document).on('click', '#sub', function () {
          $(this).closest('li p').append('<p style="margin-left: 10px;">Comments</p>');
      });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like what you could do is give the appended element an id or class and then in JQUERY tell the other element to append inside that id.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/261/)**.

You should use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the click event from bubbling :

```
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
  $('ul').append('<li> Title <input id="title" type="button" value="Add Subtitle" /></li>');
});

$('body').on('click', 'li', function () {
  $(this).append('</br>Subtitle <input class="sub" type="button" value="Comment" />');
});

$('body').on('click', 'input.sub', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(this).parent().append('<p>Comments</p>');
});
```

**NOTE 1:** The `id` should be unique in the same document use class `sub` instead.

**NOTE 2:** You need to append the comment to the parent and not directly to the input :

```
$(this).parent().append('<p>Comments</p>');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
  $('ul').append('<li> Title <input id="title" type="button" value="Add Subtitle" /></li>');
});

$('body').on('click', 'li', function () {
  $(this).append('</br>Subtitle <input class="sub" type="button" value="Comment" />');
});

$('body').on('click', 'input.sub', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(this).parent().append('<p>Comments</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+ Title" />
<ul>
  <li> Title <input id="title" type="button" value="Add Subtitle"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This exactly what I want ! Thanks you so much ! 
The only problem I see it's when for example : I create many "Subtitle section" and i want to add comments on the first one. They appears on the last section and not in the current section I just clicked =(